# Django : Link Model field to another model field configuration name

Tags: django, django-models

Giving the following models in Django :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('This is my name'),max_length=150)

class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    my_model_field_name = [...]
```

I'm tring to store in `AnotherModel.my_model_field_name` the name of `MyModel.name` field (so 'This is my name').
I would like it to be linked, so if tomorow I change the name of `MyModel.name` field by "This is my new name", I want that all my previous records of my `AnotherModel.my_model_field_name` automatically update.

Model instances are able to link to other models instances, not models themselves, right ?

Is it possible or just stupid ?

EDIT :

I found a solution : the [Django ContentType](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) table is just perfect to do that.

With content type, you can iter over field of a model, without model instance (I mean, a line in my MyModel table), so, I can for example, do something like that :

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from .models import MyModel

# get the model I want
my_model = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(MyModel)

# get all fields of this model
fields = model._meta.get_fields()

# Iterate over the fields to find the one I want, and read it's specifications
for field in fields:
    # all my stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to do this is:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('This is my name'),max_length=150)

class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    my_model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
```

So if you need to read the MyModel name field from AnotherModel you can do:

```
another_model = AnotherModel.objects.last()
another_model.my_model.name
```

In this way AnotherModel has a link to MyModel and when you change MyModel name field it will be reflected in AnotherModel objects.

Comment: Thank you for your time Mau,
Actually, the problem with your solution is that I always need to have an object of MyModel in my database to work.

I found another solution : (see my EDIT)